# intel_do_flush_locked failed: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: 16.04, xorg

I am frequently getting:

intel_do_flush_locked failed: Cannot allocate memory

when running VMD (X11 program)software in ubuntu 16.04. I have 8GB of RAM  Ubuntu 16.04.2
What should I do ??

Any idea why?

Comment: Does [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100599) cover your issue? Perhaps try the latest [mainline PPA kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D), to see if the issue has been fixed upstream.

Comment: I have installed kernel 4.12.0-041200-generic ,but till now this problem is not solved.plz help me out.

Comment: uname -a
Linux saikat 4.12.0-041200-generic #201707022031 SMP Mon Jul 3 00:32:52 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: try kernel [4.13](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13/). If your issue is the same as the bug report, the fix would not yet be in kernel 4,12.